# How to reduce the size of the table by forced new line in cells?

Tags: tables

```
\begin{table}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Source energy (keV)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Saturation thickness (mm)}  & \multirow{2}{*} {1 mean free path (mfp)} & \multirow{2}{*}{Percentage
deviation} \\
\cline{2-3}
 &  Experimental & MCNP &  & \\ 
\hline
59.54 & 20.0 & 20.8 & 14.85 & 3.8 \\ 

123 & 42.8 & 42.6 & 26.00 & 0.5 \\ 

279 & 60.4 & 59.9 & 35.13 & 0.8 \\ 

360 & 66.5 & 66.0 & 38.68 & 0.8 \\ 

511 & 77.0 & 76.1 & 44.56 & 1.2 \\ 

662 & 85.4 & 85.2 & 49.83 & 0.2 \\ 

1115 & 110 & 109.2 & 63.74 & 0.7 \\ 

1250 & 116.5 & 116.1 & 67.51 & 0.3 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

Here I want to reduce the size of the table as it is going out of the page. For this I want to make the energy (keV) of the first column to be below Source. Similarly thickness (mm) in the merged 2nd and 3rd column to be below Saturation and so on.....Please help

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5):

[**Note**: After receiving some comments from the OP regarding his/her objectives, I've chosen to rewrite my answer completely. I now separate out more distinctly the tasks of (i) pursuing steps to reduce the table's overall width and (ii) also making the table easy (or at least easier) on the reader's eye.]

To start with, here's the table produced by OP's original code. Note that it exceeds the default value of the `\textwidth` parameter used in the `article` document class:

[image]

Here's the same table, modified to reduce column widths along the lines suggested by OP in his/her posting. While this approach succeeds in reducing the width of the table to less than `\textwidth`, in my opinion the table doesn't look particularly well organized. Note that I've broken up the first header row manually into two separate rows; trying to instruct `LaTeX` to break up the line automatically won't save you much time and effort in the end since you'll need to provide information on the intended width of the `tabular` material -- information you can only get by trial and error...

[image]

To better organize the table's content, both logically and visually, I suggest applying a few further modifications:

- keep separate information about column contents and information about the units measurement in the table header,
- omit all vertical rules (since they don't add any visual clarity, only clutter...),
- use the rule-drawing commands of the `booktabs` package to getter better spacing above and below the horizontal lines, and
- align numerical data on the decimal points (done here by using the `S` column type provided by the `siunitx` package).

Aside: I don't know what the unit of measurement of a "mean free path" should be---it's probably not "mfp", right?! Not being a physicist, I must confess not knowing what a "mean free path" is...

[image]

Interestingly, the widths of the second and third tables are virtually identical.

Finally, here's the code that generates all three tables shown above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow,booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in]{geometry} % just for this example
\setlength\parindent{0pt}          % just for this example
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[t!] % [t!] location specifier just for this example
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Source energy (keV)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Saturation thickness (mm)}  
& \multirow{2}{*} {1 mean free path (mfp)} 
& \multirow{2}{*}{Percentage deviation} \\
\cline{2-3}
 &  Experimental & MCNP &  & \\ 
\hline
59.54 & 20.0 & 20.8 & 14.85 & 3.8 \\ 
123 & 42.8 & 42.6 & 26.00 & 0.5 \\ 
279 & 60.4 & 59.9 & 35.13 & 0.8 \\ 
360 & 66.5 & 66.0 & 38.68 & 0.8 \\ 
511 & 77.0 & 76.1 & 44.56 & 1.2 \\ 
662 & 85.4 & 85.2 & 49.83 & 0.2 \\ 
1115 & 110 & 109.2 & 63.74 & 0.7 \\ 
1250 & 116.5 & 116.1 & 67.51 & 0.3 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
%\centering % \centering instruction commented out to simplify comparison of widths of 2nd and 3rd table
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline 
Source & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Saturation}  & 
1 mean free & Percentage \\    energy (keV) & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{thickness (mm)} & 
path (mfp) & deviation\\    \cline{2-3}
 &  Experimental & MCNP & & \\ 
\hline
59.54 & 20.0 & 20.8 & 14.85 & 3.8 \\ 
123 & 42.8 & 42.6 & 26.00 & 0.5 \\ 
279 & 60.4 & 59.9 & 35.13 & 0.8 \\ 
360 & 66.5 & 66.0 & 38.68 & 0.8 \\ 
511 & 77.0 & 76.1 & 44.56 & 1.2 \\ 
662 & 85.4 & 85.2 & 49.83 & 0.2 \\ 
1115 & 110 & 109.2 & 63.74 & 0.7 \\ 
1250 & 116.5 & 116.1 & 67.51 & 0.3 \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h!]
%\centering  % \centering instruction commented out to simplify comparison of widths of 2nd and 3rd table
\sisetup{table-format=3.1} % provide a default numerical column format
\begin{tabular}{ @{} S[table-format=4.2] 
                     S
                     S 
                     S[table-format=2.2]
                     S[table-format=1.1] @{} }
\toprule
{Source energy} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{Saturation thickness} & 
{1 mean free path} & 
{Deviation}  \\    {(keV)} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{(mm)} & 
{(mfp)} & 
{(percent)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} % trim length of rule on both left and right
 & {Experimental} & {MCNP} \\ 
\midrule
59.54 & 20.0 & 20.8 & 14.85 & 3.8 \\ 
123 & 42.8 & 42.6 & 26.00 & 0.5 \\ 
279 & 60.4 & 59.9 & 35.13 & 0.8 \\ 
360 & 66.5 & 66.0 & 38.68 & 0.8 \\ 
511 & 77.0 & 76.1 & 44.56 & 1.2 \\ 
662 & 85.4 & 85.2 & 49.83 & 0.2 \\ 
1115 & 110 & 109.2 & 63.74 & 0.7 \\ 
1250 & 116.5 & 116.1 & 67.51 & 0.3 \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case, Source energy (keV), 1 mean free path (mfp) and Deviation (Percent) cannot be made as cell centered. How to make it cell centric look?

Comment: @KiranKU - Please be a bit more specific about what you mean by "cell centric". (The contents of all columns are currently typeset centered.) Do you mean that the units (typeset in parentheses) should be typeset left-aligned?

Comment: For instance when I look into Source energy (keV) column it is center justified in horizontal direction. But vertically, that is, top to bottom it should be center justified. Like this for other items like 1 mean free path (mfp) and Deviation (Percent)

Comment: The Source energy (keV), 1 mean free path (mfp) and Deviation (Percent) are top center justified. To be more specific, it is center horizontally justified. Is it not possible to make it  center vertically (right now it is top justified) justified also?

Comment: @KiranKU - I've rewritten my answer completely to (hopefully) better address your objectives and concerns.